# how to mock nested module response in Node.js/Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to throw and error in a method of a component called from another component than I'm testing

```
// Class1.js
class Class1 {
  getData() {
    return { data }
  }
}
module.exports = new Class1()

// Class2.js
class1 = require('./Class1')
class Class2 {
  getData() {
    try {
      let data = class1.getData()
      return { data }
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
}
module.exports = new Class2()

// Class2.spec.js
const class1 = require('./Class1')
const class2 = require('./Class2')

test("Test Class2 catch block", () => {
  jest.spyOn(class1, 'getData').mockReturnValue(new Error("Error"))
  expect(class2.getData()).toEqual(Error("Error"));
})
```

But jest.spyOn doesn't catch and throw a new Error.. What I'm doing wrong? I need to test catch block in Class2

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. You're using getData as static method but it's instance method.

Comment: sorry.. I didn't include module.exports just to simplify the question

Comment: You didn't post what is the error. The mock should work, except that your expectations are wrong. Why should it be Error instance? It will work like `.mockReturnValue('foo)` and `.toEqual({ data: 'foo' })`

Comment: I expect that spyOn will return new Error instance on getData call.. but it returns just {data} so it doesn't come into catch block of Class2.getData method

Comment: For catch block, throw an error `mockImplementation(() => throw Error('foo))` and catch it, `expect(()=>class2.getData()).toThrow('foo')`. Also this try..catch is a noop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit test solution:

`class1.js`:

```js
class Class1 {
  getData() {
    return { data };
  }
}
module.exports = new Class1();
```

`class2.js`:

```js
const class1 = require('./class1');

class Class2 {
  getData() {
    try {
      let data = class1.getData();
      return { data };
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }
}
module.exports = new Class2();
```

`class2.test.js`:

```js
const class1 = require('./class1');
const class2 = require('./class2');

describe('65258975', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('Test Class2 catch block', () => {
    const getDataSpy = jest.spyOn(class1, 'getData').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error('Error');
    });
    const actual = class2.getData();
    expect(actual).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
    expect(actual.message).toEqual('Error');
    expect(getDataSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should pass', () => {
    const getDataSpy = jest.spyOn(class1, 'getData').mockReturnValueOnce('teresa teng');
    const actual = class2.getData();
    expect(actual).toEqual({ data: 'teresa teng' });
    expect(getDataSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65258975/class2.test.js
  65258975
    ✓ Test Class2 catch block (3 ms)
    ✓ should pass

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |    87.5 |      100 |      50 |    87.5 |                   
 class1.js |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
 class2.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.976 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65258975